# Collecting data for Custom Events of Application Insights using Python

Tags: azure-application-insights, open-telemetry, azure-python-sdk

I am doing project on Python. Currently it uses OpenCensus `AzureMonitorTraceExporter` as logging handler to write data to Application Insights. It is important for the client to use `Usage` section of Application Insights (`Users`, `Events` and `Sessions` specifically). But `Usage` takes data from the `customEvents` table of Application Insights and sending writing data to `customEvents` is not supported by Open Telemetry. Is there any way now to utilize `Users`, `Events` and `Sessions` without using deprecated libraries in Python code?

Answer (score 0):

> . Is there any way now to utilize `Users`, `Events` and `Sessions` without using deprecated libraries in Python code?

AFAIK, newer versions are sending data to dependencies and custom metrics but not to CustomEvents. Below code works and sends logs to CustomEvents and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#send-events):

```
import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureEventHandler

rith_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
rith_logger.addHandler(AzureEventHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=a2dec3a2-4e8df;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/'))
rith_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
rith_logger.info('Hello, Rithwik Bojja!')
```

**`Output:`**

[image]